# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Shake device for direct update

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

When studying IBM Worklight 6.1, the modules tells that the changes in web resources can be directly updated to the device when shaking and also in case of web, we can reload the page to see the result. I did the following things to test it,

```
1. Developed a sample application in IBM Worklight 6.1.0
2. The app should connect to the worklight server, so i made connectOnStartUp:true
3. Added Android environment, build and deployed the app successfully.
3. Deployed the app to android device [version - 2.3.6]
4. Added some web resources to the app and saved the file successfully
5. If I reload the web page in the desktop, the changes are automatically reflected
```

**But, when shaking the device, I cannot receive the alert for direct update.**
Is there any changes, I have to done in order to receive the direct update.

[PDF](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/common/ssi/ecm/en/epp14077usen/EPP14077USEN.PDF)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What is this module you read which says you can invoke Direct Update by *shaking* the device? Provide a link.

A Direct Update in Worklight 6.1 will **only** happen in 2 scenarios, and **only** after the application is *re-deployed to the Worklight Server*:

1. On application launch
2. On return to the foreground from the background

---

In order to use the "shake to refresh" ability, you need to follow the instructions as provided in: [Preview web resource changes on an emulator or mobile device](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fwl_studio_tools%2Ftopics%2Fc_Prevweb_onmob.html)

**Important:**

- Shake to refresh is **not** a production feature
- Shake to refresh is **not** the same as the  "Direct Update" feature
- Shake to refresh requires using *preview* resources
- Shake to refresh is meant **only for testing**

To use "shake to refresh":

1. Create a new Worklight project and application
2. Add the Android environment
3. Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
4. Open Worklight Console and preview the Android environment
5. Copy the *preview URL* by clicking on this icon:

   [image]
6. Open the generated Android project > assets > wlclient.properties
7. Replace "index.html with the "preview URL" you've copied in step 5 above
8. Run the app on the device; verify it is working
9. Change some web resources in Eclipse
10. Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
11. Shake the device

The application resources in the device should now be refreshed.

Comment: Can you kindly refer this document http://public.dhe.ibm.com/common/ssi/ecm/en/epp14077usen/EPP14077USEN.PDF, the concept will be explained under this topic: Instant preview in browser and on device

Comment: This wasn't the answer for the question. And all know how direct update work.

Comment: **On developer’s machine: save code and refresh browser** this line purely refers to direct update.

Comment: Ya i dint develop worklight but as far as the modules i have learnt from IBM i too know how direct update works but i need to know how **On device: save code and shake device** this line can be true.

Comment: Direct Update is a production feature. Shaking a device in order to refresh the web resources is NOT a production feature, and requires alteration in the application code that is NOT supported in a productio nenvironment.

Comment: @KawineshSK, like I wrote and you didn't wait... I wrote that I will update my answer, and so I did now. Thanks for being IMPATIENT.

Comment: @KawineshSK, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.